# Python regex matching whatever matched in previous group (1 out of many)

Tags: python, regex

I have the regular expression `(?:AA|BB)(.*)(?:AA|BB)` which captures everything between the delimiters `AA` and `BB`.

The problem I encounter is that this will also match `AA...BB`. This is something that I don't want. How can I make it so that the regular expression only matches `AA...AA` and `BB...BB`?

Comment: It is a simplifaction of a real problem, right? Please provide a real life example. BTW, you can use `(AA|BB)(.*?)\1` for the `AA` and `BB`.

Comment: I think he means that he wants it to match EITHER AAsometextAA OR BBsometextBB but NOT AAsometextBB. Is that correct @Alan?

Comment: `(?:AA)(.*)(?:AA)|(?:BB)(.*)(?:BB)`

Comment: Tim007's suggestion is the correct way for non-identical leading and trailing delimiters (just non-capturing groups should be removed).

Comment: yes thank you, the problem has been solved. Sorry for the potentially trivial question. This really got me stuck. Thanks Tim & Goodies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the strings  you need to match start and end with the ***same* leading and trailing delimiters**, you just need to capture the leading delimiter and use a *backreference* inside the pattern itself:

```
(AA|BB)(.*)\1
^     ^    ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW2tC3/1)

In Python, you will have to use `re.finditer` if you want to get only the group you need, not `re.findall` that will return a tuple list (and will thus contain `AA` or `BB`). To match the substrings from `AA` till the first next `AA`, use a lazy quantifier `*?`: `(AA|BB)(.*?)\1`

A short [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XCg1Kg):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(AA|BB)(.*)\1')
test_str = "AA text AA"
print([x.group(2).strip() for x in p.finditer(test_str)])
# => ['text']
```

If you need to match strings with **mismatching leading and trailing delimiters**, you will have to use [**alternation**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
AA(.*)AA|BB(.*)BB
```

Or - a lazy quantifier version to match the closest trailing `AA`s and `BB`s:

```
AA(.*?)ZZ|BB(.*?)YY
```

Note that this will output empty elements in the results since only one group will be matched. In most Python builds, this pattern should be used with caution if you plan to use it in `re.sub` (until Python 3.5, the non-matched group is not initialized with an empty string (=None) and might throw an exception.

Here is an [extraction sample code](https://ideone.com/Ma81DL) with `re.finditer`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(AA)(.*?)(ZZ)|(BB)(.*?)(YY)')
test_str = "AA Text 1 here ZZ and BB Text2 there YY"
print("Contents:") 
print([x.group(2).strip() for x in p.finditer(test_str) if x.group(2)])
print([x.group(5).strip() for x in p.finditer(test_str) if x.group(5)])
print("Delimiters:")
print([(x.group(1), x.group(3)) for x in p.finditer(test_str) if x.group(1) and x.group(3)])
print([(x.group(4), x.group(6)) for x in p.finditer(test_str) if x.group(4) and x.group(6)])
```

Results:

```
Contents:
['Text 1 here']
['Text2 there']
Delimiters:
[('AA', 'ZZ')]
[('BB', 'YY')]
```

In real life, with very long and complex texts, these regexps can be [*unrolled*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) to make matching linear and efficient, but this is a different story.

And last but not least, **if you need to match the shortest substring from one delimiter to another that does not contain these delimiters inside**, use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
AA((?:(?!AA|ZZ).)*)ZZ|BB((?:(?!BB|YY).)*)YY
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE4oF4/1) to see the difference from [`AA(.*?)ZZ|BB(.*?)YY`](https://regex101.com/r/yE4oF4/2).

Comment: better if it's `(AA|BB)(.*?)\1`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: It is not the point, also, I added that information to my answer.

Comment: This is great .. Is there a way to capture the delimiters also in the capturing group ?

Comment: It is simple, just enclose with `(...)`: `(AA)(.*?)(ZZ)|(BB)(.*?)(YY)`

Comment: Looks like I finished :) Please next time ask a bit more precise questions.

Comment: wiktor, original OP here, thanks for your helpful response. If I may, since the `\1` already references what was matched. I was wondering if it is also possible to use back references to match the whole thing e.g. `(AA|BB)(.*)\1` = `(AA|BB)(.*)(AA|BB)` - the original undesired property (To save on typing). Or is this something that cannot be done with back references?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand. Do you want to know if we can match the whole pattern? No, it is not possible in Python `re`. You can repeat the pattern with Python PyPi `regex`  module with the PCRE-like `(?R)` recursion construct.

Comment: What good reason is there to use a raw string for the pattern and not simply double-escape the back-reference?, thus: `(AA|BB)(.*)\\1`

Comment: @markling Raw string literals are suggested in [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (see the leading passages). The reason is a leaner pattern, you only use a single backslash in the string literal. In order to avoid regular string literals for regex definition, there are such regex escapes as `\n`, `\r` and `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
AA(.*)AA|BB(.*)BB
```

look on [this](https://regex101.com/r/tD8mP0/2) example

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing. From what I understood, you want it to match either AA..AA or BB..BB, but not AA..BB which it is currently matching. I'm awful with regex, but I think this should work:
Edit: Sorry, SE formatting messed it up.

```
(?:(AA(.*)AA)|(BB(.*)BB))
```

```
>>> data = ['AAsometextAA', 'BBothertextBB', 'NotMatched', 'AAalsonotmatchedBB']
>>> matches = filter(lambda x: x is not None, [re.match("(?:(AA(.*)AA)|(BB(.*)BB))", datum) for datum in data])
>>> matches
[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x007DC078>, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x007DC288>]
>>> for match in matches:
...     print(match.group(0))
...
AAsometextAA
BBothertextBB
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
(AA(.*)AA)|(BB(.*)BB)
```

Comment: or just 
    (AA.*AA)|(BB.*BB) 
would do the trick in your specific example  .