# Regex group with pipe (2 valid patterns), negative backreference to that group and choose the other one now

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, backreference

I came across this issue a few times now and I just can't find a solution for it.

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742243/python-regex-matching-whatever-matched-in-previous-group-1-out-of-multiple-opti) I try to achieve the opposite of him.
Instead of only matching `AA...AA` and `BB...BB` I want to have a match only if the 2nd group is the opposite, maybe you could say like an if/else condition.

If `AA` search for `BB` elif `BB` search `AA` else no match.

```
AA...AA #no match
AA...BB #match
AA...CC #no match
BB...AA #match
```

In my case in the past I knew there will be exactly two patterns (AA or BB) but didn't know the order of it. So I need something like "Match pattern AA or BB, followed by anything I don't care, followed by the exact opposite of what matched earlier and nothing else".

I read several posts here at SO and the documentation of python, backreference is clear to me. I also came closer with the `negative lookahead assertion` but the problem here is that it just defines that it has to be different than the match previously, so if my captured group is `(AA|BB)` and it matched with `AA`, then (?!\1) will match anything else than `AA`.

I hope I made clear where I'm stuck and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Reading the question I think something like [`^(AA|BB).*(?!\1)(AA|BB)$`](https://regex101.com/r/NkfOac/1) could work?

Comment: it works, great! thanks! but why ?

Comment: Because the backreference to whatever is matched from our 1st group is used in the negative lookahead to prevent that exact position to be followed by that exact text. I tried to explain in steps in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could use:

```
^(AA|BB).*(?!\1)(AA|BB)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NkfOac/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(AA|BB)` - A 1st capture group to match either 'AA' *or* 'BB';
- `.*` - Match any 0+ (Greedy) characters other than newline;
- `(?!\1)` - A negative lookahead to assert position is not followed by the captured text from the 1st capture group (a backreference);
- `(AA|BB)` - A 2nd capture group to match either 'AA' *or* 'BB';
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Comment: ahhhh, ye, got it now. thanks for the explanation. without the 2nd capture group it would match anything else than the captured text from the 1st group, but with it we limit it to `(AA|BB)` again and since one of them is always negated, it just matches the other one. tricky stuff.

Comment: @Rabinzel, exactly. I couldn't have worded that better.